Reading PDF from Mongo DB gives an locale error even though there is no such variable was declared
I'm working on a spring boot project in which i want to upload pdf and other files on a Mongo db. I read through an article and found my way around it.The main issue arise when I try to retirve my pdf back, it throws me this error:
I tried Chat GPT, Gemini and what not but the error remain constant, to which i decided to delete my code and start from scratch.
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue):
'Field 'locale' is invalid in: { locale: "pdfs" }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Field 'locale' is invalid in: { locale: \"pdfs\" }", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}

What I'm tryin to achieve is that I want to extract PDF's data and display it on the webpage regardles the content.

Never heard of that error before, but I bet it would be interesting to see the code.

Changing this annotation helped me solve my issue.
@Document(collection = "pdfs") 

